# Give warning when a field is empty while making a customer

Tags: python, odoo

So basically I want to make it so that when I want to create a customer, and when I don't enter a date, it gives a warning and sets the date to default.

I know I can just put the default values like this:

```
_ defaults = { 
'date1': fields.date.context_today, 
}
```

But I need to raise an error like this one:

```
raise osv.except_osv('Warning', "No date entered, default date set")
```

I just don't know where to place it and how to call it in my custom module.

It needs to give this error when I press the "Make" button.

Comment: Have a look here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we create a new customer, a `create` method is called, So we need to override create method like.

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    if not vals.get('date1'):
        raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning!'),_('No date entered, default date set'))
    return super(res_partner, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
```

NOTE: don't forget to import below line for new custom module

```
from openerp.tools.translate import _
```